# Updating Old Links in Static Web Content

Tags: web-apps, web-development

We have a core service being migrated to a cloud vendor. This requires that we update links in our static website content to use the cloud vendor.

My tool of choice has been Microsoft PowerShell. Using the following command will perform a string search on content and identify pages needing updates.

```
$Results = Get-ChildItem -Path \\server\share\ -Force -Recurse | Select-String 'Keyword'
```

I can now loop through $Results and run additional commands for achieving the find/replace functionality I'm seeking.

I'm sure this happens all of the time so wanted to know if there is an alternative to using PowerShell and/or custom scripts.  I'm particularly interested in solutions without a steep learning curve similar to what Dreamweaver has done for website creation (i.e. WYSIWYG).  The goal is to have a solution I can recommend to users who aren't proficient in scripting so they don't have to manually update each and every page (~1000+).

EDIT - While there haven't been any recommendations I posted the steps I've been using [here](https://securitytidbits.wordpress.com/2015/07/26/updating-web-content-via-powershell/). I'm still interested to know if there are better solutions.